# How to use spatial filter in SLD file GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld

I've created SLD style for GeoServer and send it to GeoServer. But after sending GeoServer change it to another SLD.
It is source SLD I send

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>test</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>test</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>www</Name>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#ff0000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <Within>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>
                                <gml:Polygon gml:id="polygon.1" gml:srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/26713">
                                    <gml:exterior>
                                        <gml:LinearRing>
                                            <gml:posList>51.443481,32.625497,51.443481,32.971804,52.146606,32.971804,52.146606,32.625497,51.443481,32.625497</gml:posList>
                                        </gml:LinearRing>
                                    </gml:exterior>
                                </gml:Polygon>
                            </ogc:Literal>
                        </Within>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

and it is when GeoServer generate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:Title>test</sld:Title>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>www</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Within>
              <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
              <gml:Polygon>
                <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                  <gml:LinearRing>
                    <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" "/>
                  </gml:LinearRing>
                </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
              </gml:Polygon>
            </ogc:Within>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#ff0000</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
            <sld:Stroke/>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

What is the problem and what format should I use to filter SLD by polygon coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems with your input SLD:

1. You have told the parser that you are using GML 2 but are passing in GML 3 so GeoServer is ignoring the bits that it doesn't expect. So you should send a `Polygon` like:

   ```
          <gml:Polygon>
            <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
              <gml:LinearRing>
                <gml:coordinates  decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
                   51.443481,32.625497 51.443481,32.971804 52.146606,32.971804 52.146606,32.625497 51.443481,32.625497
                </gml:coordinates>
              </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
          </gml:Polygon>
   ```
2. The `Filter` element should come before the `Symbolizer` the order of the elements is fixed in the SLD standard and the XML schema. But GeoServer is relaxed about reading that so it less of a problem.

And if you are sticking with GML3 then the `PosList` should not have commas between the values.

Comment: tnx bro .  how do u understand it's gml2 or gml3?

Comment: Because the standard specifies which one to use and that form of a polygon changed between them.